# mock ldap call always returns True

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I mocked a method inside my login function so i don't use my lpdap connection.
Now i can't set the mock to false, he always returns true. Even if i insert invalid credentials it always returns me a token, while i want to get the return message "invalid credentials"
Any help?

Login function:

```
def login():

    user = request.form['user']
    passwd = request.form['passwd']

    test = ldap.bind_user(user, passwd)
    if test is None or passwd == '':
        response = jsonify(message='Invalid Credentials')
        return response ,401

    access_token = create_access_token(identity=user)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200
```

The test case:

```
    #Test to check if we get a token when the user logs in
    @patch('dev_maintenance.active_directory.ldap.bind_user')
    def test_token_return(self, bind_user):

        bind_user.verify.return_value = True
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        with tester as client:

            response = client.post(
                '/login',
                data =dict(user="hermes", passwd ="hermes"),
                follow_redirects=True)
            self.assertIn(b'Invalid Credentials, response.data)
```

Now if i changed this line to False:

```
bind_user.verify.return_value = False
```

It should do the work, but it doesn't, it returns true and therefore accepts any credentials.

test output:

```
E           AssertionError: b'Invalid Credentials' not found in b'{\n  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1Njk1MDU5OTQsIm5iZiI6MTU2OTUwNTk5NCwianRpIjoiOTg2YjQwNTYtODQyNC00ZDhjLTg2N2YtM2E3ODc4OWE4MTZjIiwiZXhwIjoxNTY5NTA2ODk0LCJpZGVudGl0eSI6Ik5vdXNlciIsImZyZXNoIjpmYWxzZSwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.RFKW2mSmqHbLtX8jBlxj9w1waug1wAe0uExPtAMkhkg"\n}\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this line to the @patch: return_value=None
With this line the mock it's override to return value none.
Then with this line `bind_user.verify.return_value = False`
I can set my return to False.